# How to solve or test the interval of Uniform Convergence of function series?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion, convergence

How to solve or test the interval of [Uniform Convergence](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformConvergence.html) of function series? ([ref2](https://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am36/Mathematica/intro/converge.html))

e.g.

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(z^{k-1}-z^k\right)$

The convergence interval of this series can be got by `SumConvergence`:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
        
SumConvergence[z^(k-1)-z^k, k]
    
(* Abs[z] < 1* )
```

But `Abs[z] < 1` is **NOT** the **Uniform Convergence** interval of the series. To test for Uniform Convergence, use [Abel's uniform convergence test](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelsUniformConvergenceTest.html) or the [Weierstrass M-test](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassM-Test.html). In Wolfram Language Documentation '[DiscreteLimit](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteLimit.html)', examples are provided to illustrate the uniform convergence of series through function `Plot`. And there is also a [demonstration](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/UniformConvergenceOfASequenceOfFunctions/).

I made some `Plot` for the sum of series of infinite terms `s` and the sum of series of the first n terms `sn` in `Abs[z] < 1`. It can be seen from the `Plot` that this series is not Uniform Convergence.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
ak = z^(-1 + k) - z^k;
an = z^(-1 + n) - z^n;
sn[n_] = 1 - z + Sum[ak, {k, 2, n}]
s = 1 - z + Sum[ak, {k, 2, Infinity}]
r = Abs[s - sn[n]]
Plot[{s, sn[4], sn[8], sn[12], sn[16], sn[24]} // Evaluate, {z, 0, 1.5}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

For comparison, the **Uniform Convergence** interval of this series, namely `Abs[z] < 1/2`, is plotted.

```
Plot[{s, sn[4], sn[8], sn[12], sn[16], sn[24]} // Evaluate, {z, 0, 
  0.5}, PlotRange -> {0.9, 1}, PlotLabels -> "Expressions", 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

**So my question is:**

Is there a way to solve or test the interval of **Uniform Convergence** of function series by MMA?

It is best to have universality and not only applicable to this example.

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you. The question has been edited.

Comment: Why is abs(z)<1 not the uniform convergence region?

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau  For any ε> 0, check if there is an N(ε), When n>N(ε)  $\lim _{p \rightarrow \infty}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p} w_k(z)\right|=\left|S-S_n\right|<\varepsilon$  , so $\left(\frac{1}{|z|}\right)^n>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}, n \ln \frac{1}{|z|}>\ln \frac{1}{\varepsilon}, n>\frac{\ln \varepsilon^{-1}}{\ln |z|^{-1}}=\frac{\ln \varepsilon}{\ln |z|}$, But obviously there is no N(ε), for any z within | z |<1, $N(\varepsilon)>\frac{\ln \varepsilon}{\ln |z|}$.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau I edited the question and added a comparison between the `Plot` of this series in the Uniform Convergence interval `Abs[z] < 1/2` and the Non-Uniform Convergence interval `Abs[z] < 1`.

Comment: For any `0<=p<1` it converges uniformly on `0<=z<=p`.